# Working with DefaultOrEmpty in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

In case of Default or Empty I want to  supply some value:

```
string[] str = {string.Empty, "hello", "world" };

var select = str.Select(s => s).DefaultIfEmpty("nodata");

GridView1.DataSource = Select;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Why did my grid not get filled with:

```
nodata
hello
world
```

Instead, I receive:

```
hello
world
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DefaultIfEmpty supplies a default value if the sequence is empty - you are trying to use it to substitute empty values in the sequence (i.e. string.Empty). You should use:

```
var select = str.Select(s => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "nodata" : s);
```

Comment: +1. Ah yes. I didn't see the default or empty requirement bit!

Answer (score 0):

Default if empty is used to do outer joins. Try this...

```
  var select = str.Select(s => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "nodata" : s);
```